# Automatically send email with PDF of sheets weekly

Tags: google-sheets, automation

Is it possible to automatically send weekly emails to a list of recipients of  PDFs of each sheet in Google Spreadsheet? I've looked around but haven't found any ways to do this, only found ways to send the actual email, but not with the sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible by using a Google Sheets add-ons and [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) (GAS). Please checkout the help article [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en) to learn the basics.

If you decide to use GAS, you will need a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to send your email weekly.

Below is a related question that may help you to write your own script:

[Trying to send email from Google Sheets with image attachment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79002/trying-to-send-email-from-google-sheets-with-image-attachment)